# VB.net Regex extract data from string

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, string, ldap

I am trying to extract data from a string using Regex in VB.net. This is my string

```
CN=firstname lastname/OU=orgunit/O=org;shortname
```

I am basically trying to retrieve

```
firstname lastname (together)
orgunit
org
shortname
```

can someone please help me.

Comment: Where is this data coming from?  That looks like Domino's naming syntax, but the change from /CN= and /OU= to ,O= is very odd.  Is that a typo or really correct?

Comment: Yah it was a typo, but with thejh regex, I was able to fix it. I edit it to the correct domino syntax. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regexp:

```
^/CN=([^/]*)/OU=([^,]*),O=([^;]*);(.*)$
```

(first capture group is name, second is orgunit, third is org, fourth is shortname)